# Create self signed certificate with TLS

Tags: ssl, certificate, self-signed

Environment: 
Windows Server 2003
IE 6/7
IIS 6
ASP.NET 3.5 Framework application

**Self Signed Certificate**

I have created self signed SSL certificate using IIS resource kit and have configured the same in IIS 6.0. Web App works as intended.

Now the client wants me to use TLS instead of SSL. I dont see an option to create TLS using IIS resource tool kit.

Please advice.

Thanks
BV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A self-signed certificate is a self-signed certificate. It is specified by X.509. Its creation has nothing to do with SSL or TLS. You can use the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you do not need to create a new certificate to use the TLS protocol. The TLS protocol can use the same self signed certificate if the flags are set properly.

Did you try just enabling TLS in IIS6?